# mysql copy table in server to local server with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, bulkinsert

I want to copy a table data in a server to local server with PHP.

This is the script I have

```
<?php

$h_local = "localhost";
$u_local = "root";
$p_local = "";
$db_local = "";


$h_server = "localhost";
$u_server = "root";
$p_server = "";
$db_server = "";

$server = new mysqli($h_server,$u_server,$p_server,$db_server);

$local = new mysqli($h_local,$u_local,$p_local,$db_local);

$result = $local->query("SELECT * FROM b_barang");

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  foreach ($row as $field => $value) {
    $fields .= "$field, ";
    $values .= "'$value', ";
  }
  // remove trailing ", " from $fields and $values
  $fields = preg_replace('/, $/', '', $fields);
  $values = preg_replace('/, $/', '', $values);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO b_barang ($fields) VALUES ($values)";
  $arr[] = $sql;

}


foreach($arr as $a){
    $server->query($a);
    echo $a."<br><br>";
}
?>
```

The result is in the first array like

> `FIRST RESULT`
>
> INSERT INTO b_barang (Kode, Nama, Satuan, HP, PPN, Diskon, HJ,
>   Kemasan, Margin, Saldo, TglPesan, Batmin, Batmak, HPAwal, PPNAwal,
>   DiskonAwal, HJAwal, IsiKemasan, HPKemasan, HPKemAwal, HPPAverage,
>   HPPAverageAwal, Jenis, HPP, HPPAwal, SaldoTemp, SaldoInput, Supplier)
>   VALUES ('3', 'barang 3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
>   '', '0', '', '0', '0', '0', '0', '', '', '', '', '', '0', '0', '')

and the next result is wrong like adding values from first time result

> ```
> `SECOND RESULT`
> ```
>
> INSERT INTO b_barang (Kode, Nama, Satuan, HP, PPN, Diskon, HJ,
>   Kemasan, Margin, Saldo, TglPesan, Batmin, Batmak, HPAwal, PPNAwal,
>   DiskonAwal, HJAwal, IsiKemasan, HPKemasan, HPKemAwal, HPPAverage,
>   HPPAverageAwal, Jenis, HPP, HPPAwal, SaldoTemp, SaldoInput,
>   SupplierKode, Nama, Satuan, HP, PPN, Diskon, HJ, Kemasan, Margin,
>   Saldo, TglPesan, Batmin, Batmak, HPAwal, PPNAwal, DiskonAwal, HJAwal,
>   IsiKemasan, HPKemasan, HPKemAwal, HPPAverage, HPPAverageAwal, Jenis,
>   HPP, HPPAwal, SaldoTemp, SaldoInput, Supplier) VALUES ('3', 'barang
>   3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0', '', '0', '0',
>   '0', '0', '', '', '', '', '', '0', '0', '''1', 'barang1', '', '', '',
>   '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0', '', '0', '0', '0', '0', '',
>   '', '', '', '', '0', '0', '')

as you can see the values in result 2 adding values from result 1.

how can I solved it?

Comment: Silly point: But why are you running the queries you built on `$server` I thought you wanted to insert this data into `$local`

Comment: @RiggsFolly i need data from server to insert  for local

Comment: Yes... See my answer, maybe that will explain it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is clear out the `$fields` and `$values` variables each time round your while loop. Currently you are adding the second query to the first and then the third query to the first and second.. etc

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    // clear out these 2 variables before starting another iteration
    $fields = '';
    $values = '';

  foreach ($row as $field => $value) {
    $fields .= "$field, ";
    $values .= "'$value', ";
  }
  // remove trailing ", " from $fields and $values
  $fields = preg_replace('/, $/', '', $fields);
  $values = preg_replace('/, $/', '', $values);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO b_barang ($fields) VALUES ($values)";
  $arr[] = $sql;

}
```

You may also want to check this loop as it appears to be applying the INSERTS to the Server and not the Local database

```
foreach($arr as $a){
    // Should this line
    //$server->query($a);
    // be
    $local->query($a);
    echo $a."<br><br>";
}
```